# WordPress automatically downscaled images larger that original

Tags: images, uploads, media

I have a real head head-scratcher. I am trying to boost the performance of my wife's website. One of the things I identified as potential issue was the size of image files. I am somewhat aware photo editor so I always tried to use the quality slider in GIMP to keep the file size reasonable. I've started to play with quality settings further in order to squeeze more performance but when I looked at my images via filezilla I was shocked, screenshot attached. As I understand, Wordpress automatically makes multiple resolutions of uploaded images in order to serve them to differently sized screens and thus save bandwidth but look at the file sizes I got!

[image: Image sizes after WP down-scaling]

in most cases image one step **smaller in resolution is twice as large in disc space** a in some cases more than three.
I tried to find what compression settings WP uses and it seems that after version 4.5 it should be 82% which doesn't seem to be the case for me.
I am certain that I did not tamper with this parameter by any custom filter but I cannot be sure if about the theme or plugins that I use.

here is the info I have on media handling (headers roughly translated, my WP dashboard is in Polish):

```
Active Editor : WP_Image_Editor_Imagick
Version of ImageMagick : 1690
ImageMagick version designation : ImageMagick 6.9.10-57 Q16 amd64 2019-09-05 https://imagemagick.org
Imagick resource limits : 
    area: 384 GB
    disk: 9.2233720368548E+18
    file: 7500
    map: 384 GB
    memory: 192 GB
    thread: 1
Version of GD : 2.2.5
Version of Ghostscript : Could not verify if Ghostscript was installed
```

I would like to ask 2 questions.

1. Is there a way to find out what are the current compression settings used by my WordPress ?
2. I think I can write a script that will take all those automatically generated files in the uploads. directory and re-compress them to my desired size. I do not know if WP will not freak out that the files were changed externally and thus my question : would such approach be even advisable ?

WP version that I use is: version: 5.2.7

Comment: Can you check if your WordPress is using ImageMagick or GD please? Tools, Site Health, Info, Media Handling - the answer might be specific to that. But I'd guess it's just using whatever the default settings are for whichever tool.

Comment: But 2: no, WordPress won't notice if you recompress the files yourself. There's a slight chance it'll re-recompress them at some point in the future though and overwrite your version, but I think that's generally only done when manually triggered.

Comment: @Rup I've edited my question with info you asked for, in shot: it is ImageMagick.

Comment: Apologies, turns out there's a combined mechanism for both ImageMagick and GD so I didn't need to know that. Yes, the default quality number is 82% but I guess different tools have a different interpretation of what 82% means.

Comment: If you want to change the global WordPress quality setting then you can hook either the [wp_editor_set_quality](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_editor_set_quality/) or the [jpeg_quality](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/jpeg_quality/) hooks; or there's the [image-quality](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-quality/) plugin that looks OK to me and does this for you (via the jpeg_quality hook).

Comment: However I can't see a way to vary this per image, to mirror your careful tweaking. As far as I know JPEG or EXIF don't store a quality estimate for us to read out and reuse, and as above the same number might mean different things to different programs anyway. It might also be possible to reject image resizes that end up larger than the original, and either just use the original or try lower quality settings to match, but that's going to be more work to code up. I'm not sure what to suggest here.

Comment: @Rup At this point I pretty much decided to try a python script script to compress the images, I have couple of ideas as to how to manage the quality and other issues you warned me about. I'll be sure to post the solution when I'm done. 
I Understand that this is a workaround and the root of the problem is not addressed at all but frankly, I prefer this solution, gives me more control.